# Spring boot - Cannot change default 8080 port on TomCat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I need to change the 8080 port on my spring boot application, getting it from an external config file.

I have my application.properties in /config directory and I added

server.port = 8090

When the app starts, the logger says something like:

```
2016-08-12 14:41:04 INFO  Http11NioProtocol:180 - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
2016-08-12 14:41:05 INFO  Http11NioProtocol:180 - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
```

so i think that the property has been taken... but if i try to reach a web service on it

```
10.10.8.133:8090/client?numeroClient=4
```

I got a 0 error and if I try to call

```
10.10.8.133:8080/client?numeroClient=4
```

I got the right response...
Which is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there's, as far as I know, 2 ways to change default server port for spring boot :

**application.properties**

In your application.properties file, you just have to add :

```
server.port=9080
```

If it's not working, it's most likely because your `application.properties` configuration file is not taken into account.

You can still change the location with JVM properties like :

```
java -Dspring.config.location=/random/location/directory -jar spring-boot-application.jar
```

From Spring docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

**JVM properties**

When you start your spring boot application you can add JVM properties like :

```
java -Dserver.port=9080 -jar spring-boot-application.jar
```

**Documentation :**

- Change the HTTP port : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-change-the-http-port
- Customizing embedded servlet containers : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-customizing-embedded-containers

Answer (score 2):

If your project is `maven modular`, make sure in your `pom` file packaging type is **jar**, becuase if your root project packageing type is pom, then configuring `application.properties` for changing server port will not be affected.

Answer (score -1):

By default spring uses port 8080 and depending on your system it may be in use, thus causing problems for Spring, so:
Modify the application.properties file and only add
server.port = XXXX